# How to prevent logging Rails stack trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm trying to reduce the amount of noise in my logs and would like to disable Rails from logging the stack trace during errors.

Since I am using an error reporting service (Honeybadger.io) I don't need to see the stack trace in the logs as it's already available in the exception report from the error handling service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs you should be able to add a backtrace silencer that excludes every line by returning true in the block.

But, at least with Rails 4.2.5.2, this doesn't appear to be working and even if it did work you would still end up with a line in log about the exception.

Accidentally I discovered that if you raise an error inside a silencer block that this will suppress the error message and the entire backtrace which turns out to be exactly what I'm looking for.

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |_line| raise }
```

Combining this hack with the [concise_logging gem](https://github.com/gshaw/concise_logging) I can now have logs that look like the following:

[image]

Comment: Gerry, probably my approach is bit better, see my answer above

Comment: The reason a silencer returning `true` doesn't help is that the `DebugExceptions` middleware that logs the errors will default to logging an unfiltered trace if the filtered one is empty. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1b86d90136efb98c7b331a84ca163587307a49af/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb#L179-L180

Answer (score 2):

The default Rails middleware `DebugExceptions` is what [logs the errors](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1b86d90136efb98c7b331a84ca163587307a49af/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb#L101).

You can remove it with `config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions)` in your `config/environment.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer` works, but I woulnd call its behaviour predictable

https://github.com/vipulnsward/rails/blob/ecc8f283cfc1b002b5141c527a827e74b770f2f0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb#L155-L156

Since `application_trace` is empty(This is because error is not from user code but route error), we are falling back to `framework_trace`, which does not filter it (it filters only noise).

You can solve it with creating your own log_formatter. In your `development.rb` and/or `test.rb` add

```
config.log_formatter = SilentLogger.new
config.log_formatter.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /lib/ }
```

And create simple class in models with only method `call` required. There you can modify your backtrace as you wish.

```
class SilentLogger
  def initialize
    @silencers = []
  end

  def add_silencer(&block)
    @silencers << block
  end

  def call(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    backtrace = (String === msg) ? "#{msg}\n" : "#{msg.inspect}\n"

    return backtrace if @silencers.empty?

    @silencers.each do |s|
      backtrace = backtrace.split("\n").delete_if { |line| s.call(line) }
    end

    backtrace.join("\n")
  end
end
```